# Responding to a change trigger handler on button click

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockitdev/AS6GB/35/)

In the following example, if you manually change the text in the text box, you get a different message beneath the text box.

I want the same behaviour if you click one of the buttons (i.e. if you click the button Set as 4) you should see Mid-to-Mod frail appear below the text input.

My HTML

```
<input type="text" id="total-frailty-score" value="9" />

<div id="frail-category-area">
    <div id="frail-category"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="a" value="Set as 4" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Set as 2" />
<input type="button" id="c" value="Set as 7" />
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
$(function () {

function FrailCategory() {

    if ($('#total-frailty-score').val() ==  9) {
        $('#frail-category').text('Terminally')
    } else if ($('#total-frailty-score').val() >=  1 && $('#total-frailty-score').val() <=  3) {
        $('#frail-category').text('Pre-Frail')
    } else if ($('#total-frailty-score').val() >=  4 && $('#total-frailty-score').val() <=  6) {
        $('#frail-category').text('Mid-to-Mod frail')
    } else if ($('#total-frailty-score').val() >=  7 && $('#total-frailty-score').val() <=  8) {
        $('#frail-category').text('Severely frail')
    }
}

    $('#total-frailty-score').change(FrailCategory).triggerHandler("change");

});

$('#a').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('4');
});

$('#b').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('2');
});

$('#c').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('7');
});
```

Comment: Side note: [cache your jQuery objects](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You could manually fire the change event in your click handlers:

```
$('#a').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('4').change();
});
```

Although I would suggest rewriting everything: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PWuC/)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the same function that is bound to your change handler from the click handlers:

```
$('#a').click(function() {
    scoreBox.val('4');
    setFrailText();
});

$('#b').click(function() {
    scoreBox.val('2');
    setFrailText();
});

$('#c').click(function() {
    scoreBox.val('7');
    setFrailText();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AS6GB/38/

You should also be [caching your jQuery objects](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects) instead of selecting on them over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Just call your FrailCategory() after ur click function.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AS6GB/40/)

```
$('#a').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('4');
    FrailCategory() ;
});

$('#b').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('2');
    FrailCategory() ;
});

$('#c').click(function() {
    $('#total-frailty-score').val('7');
    FrailCategory() ;
});
```